# How can I recursively get all non-system directories?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have recently disabled 8.3 file names on my NTFS volume and noticed a significant decrease (it only takes 25% as much time now) in the amount of time it takes to enumerate a new directory with a very large amount of files. However, this does not apply to existing files.

To change that, I want to create an exe that will recursively go through all of the files on the drive that are not in system folders, move them to a temp directory, and move them back in order to force the 8.3 file name removal on them. I already know how to enumerate through the files of a directory and perform this action on each of them, but I'm not quite sure how to get a list of all the directories on the disk without any system directories included. Is there an Attribute I can look for within a DirectoryInfo object? If not, what other approach can I take to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you defining 'System Directory'?

Comment: By system directory, I mean any directory that is vital to the OS. Is there any directory outside of C:\Windows\ that I should be concerned about? I'm not sure if there are any drivers or something located elsewhere.

Comment: Aren't System files marked as System files with an attribute?

Comment: I'm not too certain about that, but if possible, I would prefer to skip the entire directory that contains system files to begin with rather than going into them and checking the files themselves.

Comment: Its not only the C:\Windows directory you should be concerned about. C:\System Volume Information, C:\Recovery, and others can also be critical. Relying on the 'system' attribute does not fit your definition, since C:\Program Files, C:\Documents and Settings, etc. all have this flag. - If you need a one-time-solution for your own system: just exclude the directories that you don't want manually (`if (dirName != "foo" && dirName != "bar" && ...`) and move on... :)

Comment: As a last resort, I may try that, but in the case that there is some directory that I might not know of that also contains such files, I would like a solution that is more robust and applicable to different machines, since I am planning on expanding this onto my other machines as well. Is there any Win32 API that may help me get the information I need?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  I believe this is what you are after...
See [FileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) for more information.

```
public void RecursivePathWalk(string directory)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        if (IsSystem(filePath))
            continue;

        DoWork(filePath);
    }

    string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
    foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories)
    {
        if (IsSystem(subDirectory))
            continue;

        RecursivePathWalk(subDirectory);
    }
}

public void DoWork(string filePath)
{
    //Your logic here
}

public bool IsSystem(string path)
{
    FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);
    return (attributes & FileAttributes.System) != 0;
}
```

Comment: My C:\Windows folder on my standard Windows 7 installation does not have the system flag set.

Comment: I can confirm what Doug has said.